# Append javascript function to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add the following code to the footer of my page, but I have to do it using javascript code.

**Code I need to add**:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, w, c) {
        (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
            try {
                    w.yaCounter39519115 = new Ya.Metrika({
                    id:39519115,
                    clickmap:true,
                    trackLinks:true,
                    accurateTrackBounce:true
                });
            } catch(e) { }
        });

        var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            s = d.createElement("script"),
            f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

        if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
            d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
        } else { f(); }
    })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
```

**What I tried to add:**

```
 $('#footer').append('<script type="text/javascript">' + (function (d, w,.... + '</script>');
```

However, this does not work for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you just put this code on the page?

Comment: Why do you want to put in footer ? it can be executed from anywhere

Comment: w[c] = w[c]????

Comment: the function need to be inside string otherwise it will be exected before appening the script and the result of the function execution will be appended to script in your case it will be `<script>undefined</script>`

Comment: @degr that's how you add default argument in javascript before ES6, `foo = foo || [];`

Comment: I understand, it mean that you can use multiple count of some yandex counters

Comment: The page is a part of wikimedia framework, so I cannot just add the code to the footer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your javascript in a separate `.js` file and then you need to use the `document.createElement` method to add/append your script to your footer block.

Try the below snippet.

```
var scriptSource = document.createElement('script');
var scriptURL = 'your_script_file_url_goes_here';
scriptSource.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptSource.src = scriptURL ;
$("#footer").append(scriptSource);
```

Hope this helps!.